# RAID6 REBUILD - Virtual Drive not importable

Tags: raid, storage, raid6

Good morning,
Last week, the heatsink of our LSI9271-8i Raid card dropped off from the card and the card is dead. It is an 8 disk x 10TB (Slot7 is hot spare) RAID6.

Well, we have another LSI9271-8i, same model as dead card.
When we first attached the alive card, this was the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/86C7Q.jpg
After a Firmware upgrade to match the FW version of the dead card, this is my current situation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s3Vu.jpg

My RAID had 2 virtual drives (I think), according to VirtualDrive preview:
1-OS drive
2-Data drive

So, what should be my next step?
What can I do with disk at Slot4, marked as rebuild?
Could I do the rebuild prior to recover the virtual drive?
Why is virtual drive set as "Not importable VD"?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems there is no 2 VD to import, but one VD mistakenly showed up twice. That may mean controller is confused. Try to remove both hot spare and rebuild disk to see if controller would not be confused. You may also want to clear RAID configuration from the controller when no disks are attached.

Comment: storcli utility can be more verbose about what happening. You can run it in rescue linux 
image booted from CD/USB

Comment: Thank you guys! I will dettach all my drives an clear configuration.
@kab00m My intention is boot an external windows and run megaraid to get logs, should it be enough? Or even run storcli from Windows, could it be? There is not problem with ubuntu but I already have an external windows installation. Thank you!!

Comment: There is no difference to run storcli from either windows or ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Creating a new virtual disk with the previous parameters, clearing any foreign configuration previously, and adding a new config without initializing.

This KB help me a lot:
https://www.broadcom.com/support/knowledgebase/1211161498332/unable-to-import-foreign-configuration---deleted-my-megaraid-arr